# Using GPEdit to lock down a local account on Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, group-policy

I have a few local accounts on a Windows XP machine.

The local account is called localUser1 ... localUser16

I need to lock the accounts down so the ONLY application that is allowed to run is Notepad.exe

All domain accounts, local Admin accounts should be unaffected.

Is this possible? If so then how to execute it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XP doesn't have the ability to use gpedit to affect different local users differently, so all local accounts would get settings applied, even admins.

Windows 7 has this capability called "Multiple Local GPO" http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766291%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

For XP there is a really old tool called "XP Security Console" by Doug Knox that might help you: http://www.dougknox.com/xp/utils/xp_securityconsole.htm

Comment: This is what happened to me before. Now I have to image 20+ PC's because we can't reverse the GPEdit to deny all applications except notepad. We cant even open GPEdit

Comment: That's where the 2nd tool comes in.  It is per user (the free version you have to do it logged in as the user you want to change)

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do here is allow gpedit.msc and notepad.exe to be run. Non admin users won't be able to edit group policy but it will allow the admin users to "disable computer and user policies" after logging in in order to "unlock" the workstation to make changes.

Comment: Why not just add an ACE to the GPO to deny Apply Group Policy to admins?

Comment: Nevermind - forgot they are local accounts.